# Ant task to list files on https

Tags: ant

I need to list the file names in a folder on https

if it would have been FTP I could have used

```
<ftp action="list" server="" userid="" password="" listing="list.txt">
    <fileset>
        <include name="*suite*.zip" />
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

What would be the equivalent for https?

Comment: i do not think https has any API to give you folders. some web servers do allow you to epose simple 'index' files. Am guessing you will have to make your own ant task for that. start with a simple open src one and build on that using http components to connect to the index page (if it exits) and parse it to get listing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the list of HTTP methods, there is no action that allows to "list" files. HTTP is a protocol for transferring content like HTML and it depends on how the server responds to the URI request.

The closest task I can think of is [`get`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html):

```
<get src="https://some_address/" dest="output.txt" />
```

You would then need to parse the output to retrieve the list of files.

Another option (though never tried it before) seems to use the 3rd party [`httpget`](http://fikin-ant-tasks.sourceforge.net/fikin-ant-tasks.html#httpget). It has an attribute to accept untrusted or self-signed certificates.